# How to get the quarter date output for the below query

Tags: sql

I have the below code, which is giving me the data for each monthend date. I want this to provide me with the quarter end dates only.

```
DECLARE @LegalName AS VARCHAR(255) = LOWER ('xx')
DECLARE @IndexId AS VARCHAR (255) ='xx'-------------provide the index legal name

; with CTE as (
SELECT DISTINCT ph.[Date],ph.IndexShares, EDD.[Close], EDD.[LocalCurrency], dsm.PerformanceId, ds.SecurityName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS SecurityName, ds.TICKER COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS Ticker, icm.SectorName COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS SectorName,icm.IndustryName, ds.ISIN COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS ISIN, coc.MsCountry,--C.COUNTRY as Country,

        ph.MarketValue, ph.ThirdPartyId, ds.SEDOL COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN AS SEDOL, ds.MIC
        
            FROM TimeSeries..PortfolioHoldings ph               
                INNER JOIN TimeSeries.dbo.EquityDailyData AS EDD
                         ON PH.ThirdPartyId = EDD.ThirdPartyId
                          AND PH.[Date] = EDD.[Date]                
                LEFT JOIN StagingData..DMA_DimSecurityMapping dsm
                        ON dsm.ThirdPartyId  = ph.ThirdPartyId 
                        AND ph.Date BETWEEN dsm.StartDate AND dsm.EndDate
                LEFT JOIN StagingData.dbo.DMA_DimCompanyCoC coc
                        ON dsm.CompanyId=coc.CompanyId  
                        AND ph.Date BETWEEN coc.StartDate AND coc.EndDate
                LEFT JOIN StagingData.dbo.DMA_DimCompanyIndustry dci
                        ON dsm.CompanyId= dci.CompanyId
                        AND ph.Date BETWEEN dci.StartDate AND dci.EndDate
                LEFT JOIN IDW.[dbo].[GECSIndustryMapping]icm
                        ON dci.IndustryId= icm.IndustryCode
                        AND ph.Date BETWEEN dsm.StartDate AND dsm.EndDate


                LEFT JOIN StagingData.dbo.DMA_DimSecurity ds
                        ON dsm.PerformanceId = ds.PerformanceId
                        AND ph.Date BETWEEN ds.StartDate AND ds.EndDate
                WHERE ph.PortfolioId in
                
                                (
                                    SELECT CAST (PortfolioId AS VARCHAR (16)) COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN
                                    FROM MSTAR_INDEX..Indexidentifier 
                                    WHERE Name = @LegalName
                                    AND IndexStatus = 1
                                )

                            AND ph.[Date] IN (SELECT MAX([Date]) FROM Timeseries.dbo.IndexLevel WHERE IndexId = @IndexId AND YEAR([Date])>'2020' AND Date <'2022-09-01' GROUP BY EOMONTH([Date]))

)

select t.[Date],SectorName, IndustryName, SUM([Weight]) as Weights
from (select DISTINCT *, 100*CAST (c.MarketValue as FLoat)/sum (c.MarketValue) over (Partition by c.[Date]) as [Weight]
     FROM CTE as c
    ) as t

GROUP BY t.[Date],SectorName,IndustryName
```

The desired result would be to get the data for each quarterend date for 2022 - March 31 2022, June 30th 2022 , Sept 30th 2022 , December 30th 2022 ( all the quarter end date / date preceding the quarterend which is on weekend )

Comment: I'd suggest creating a calendar table. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression to calculate the end of quarter. Looks a bit ugly but works.

```sql
DECLARE @date DATETIME = '20230421'
SELECT EOMONTH(@date, CASE DATEPART(MONTH, @date) % 3 WHEN 1 THEN 2 WHEN 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```